# JSF selectOneRadio indentation

Tags: css, jsf, styles, radio-button, indentation

Is there anyway to indent a set of radio buttons? I want it to look like the following:

```
o Item 1
o Item 2
    o Item 2.1
    o Item 2.2
o Item 3
```

I tried just applying a style to it but it doesn't work.

```
<style>
    .indent {
        text-indent: 3em;
    }
</style>

<p class="indent">test</p>

<h:selectOneRadio layout="pageDirection" value="#{myBean}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Item 1" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Item 2" />   <!-- also okay if item 2 is not selectable and item 2.1 and 2.2 are -->
    <p class="indent">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2.1"  itemLabel="Item 2.1" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2.2" itemLabel="Item 2.2" />
    </p>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Item 3" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a margin instead of indent?

```
.myIndent { 
    margin-left: 3em; 
}
```

Have a look at http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/
as well, they cover radio button styling.

Comment: I tried your margin-left suggestion but it didn't work on the radio items, just the "test" text.

Comment: try and get rid of the p tags, and just add a second div class..
<div class="indent2">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2.1"  itemLabel="Item 2.1" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2.2" itemLabel="Item 2.2" />
</div>
.indent2 { 
    margin-left: 3em; 
}

Comment: I tried it with the div instead, exactly like in your example (added the missing style tags) but it still doesn't work. I suspect this will work for regular html radio boxes but if I use JSF's selectOneRadio, JSF ignores any type of styling while converting it from its "selectOneRadio" format to html's radio/tables.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to display your radio buttons as a list. Add the `layout` attribute with `pageDirection` value to the `<h:selectOneRadio />` tag component to achieve it:

```
<h:selectOneRadio layout="pageDirection" value="#{myBean}">
    <!-- your items go here... -->
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: Thank you. It appears I needed that layout attribute to make it list downward but what I am really asking is to indent specific items in the list. I also added a visual example to make it more clear.